# GeoServer Disk Quota problem

Tags: geoserver

On a Windows Server 2016 and GeoServer  2.19.1. - I'm facing the following problem.

The Disk Quota system doesn't work - once reached the set limit it doesn't remove the tiles and slowly the disk gets full.

Any advice?

[image: Disk Quota Problem]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: That's a small cache... if you have users doing lots of tile requests, they might be generating tiles faster than the quota can reclaim them. Also, the quota cleanup activates once every 60 seconds, so you need to plan for overshoots, they will happen.